# Rails initialize default value in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a web application, and i want to store user prefered stylesheet in session, and i need to fill it by default to some default till user not log-in or etc. For this purpouses i use session (probably not best solution but it does not matter), and i need a place where i can initialize this variable. Example :

```
session[:user_theme] = 'default.css'
```

i dont want to check it every time before filter in some function, i want to initialize it once and then only change via UI. 
Can you help me to find better place to do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the before-filter-option? That seems the easiest and fastest way to do it, you only need a method with `session[:user_theme] ||= 'default.css' in it as filter. place it in you application_controller and you'r done.

Comment: Thx for answer. I have that right now. But why i need to check it every time (As i understand, before_filter executes on every request?)? I think its costs almost nothing, but is there are no place where i can initialize it?

Comment: I believe this is the standard way to do these things. I agree, it would be nice to do it only once, out of principle, but the costs are really quite nothing in comparison to all the rest rails is doing when processing a request. Guess you have to be pragmatic sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

I think application controller is a good place. Something similar should work.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_theme

  def set_theme
    session[:user_theme] ||= (current_user ? current_user.preferred_theme : 'default.css')
  end
end
```

EDIT

oops i did misread question. But i do agree with Niels, it is the best place to put. And ||= aperator will initialize it only once.

Comment: Yes you are right. But keep in mind, this is a stateless world. This "check in every request" cost is nothing. That's just my opinion. But i d like hear about other solutions.